# Get select table contents using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a table, from a site, using Greasemonkey script.
Here's how this table looks:

```
<table class="OCalaisBox">
<tr class="OCalaisHeadRow">
    <td colspan="4" class="OCalaisTitleBar">Topics in this article</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="OCalaisList indexNormalText">
        <div class="OCalaisHeader">Country</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/category/country/nigeria">Nigeria</a></li>
            <li><a href="/category/country/bosnia-and-herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to retrieve, say, "Nigeria" and "Bosnia and Herzegovina".

Editor's note:  [Here's a live page with this structure.](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2014/06/it-dog-life-sierra-leone-vet-2014616135227592590.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a list of countries in the article, your easiest bet is to key off of the link `href`s provided.  Other answers' approaches will work for your sample HTML, but fetch a whole lot of other stuff on [the actual page (sample)](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2014/06/it-dog-life-sierra-leone-vet-2014616135227592590.html).

The simplest (readable) code:

```
//--- Get the country links:
var cntryLinks  = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href^='/category/country/']");
//--- Extract the country names:
var nameList    = [].map.call (cntryLinks, function (cLink) {
    return cLink.textContent; 
} );
//--- Convert to text:
var countryStr  = nameList.join (", ");

//--- Display:
console.log ("Countries: " + countryStr);
alert ("Countries: " + countryStr);
```

---

Keep in mind that that site only puts this information up on (most) news articles, NOT all pages.

Comment: Assumed that nothing more tahn countries are wanted, what isn't mentioned in the Question, an XPath expression would also do the task without relying on a hyperref location. `nameList = GM_xpath({path: "//div[@class='OCalaisHeader' and text()='Country']/following-sibling::ul/li", all:true}).map(function(item){return item.textContent;});` It means, the list items must follow a div.OCaliasHeader with content=="Country". Even more restrictive "table.OCalaisBox" could be additionally specified in case of the site you have linked.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all elements you look for by their CSS selectors. In this given case the following oneliner would do the job:

```
array = ( [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.OCalaisList>ul>li>a'), function(item) { return item.textContent; }));

// output the array to console (press ctrl+shift+k in Firefox)
console.log(array);
```

`map()` is a method of `Array.prototype`. The returned result of `querySelectorAll()` method is iteratable but actually not an array and doesn't have this method on it's own. `map()` will work as a method of the result, if you put it in context with the `call()` method.

`querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` of all CSS selector matches you specify.

`map()` calls a callback function on each element of the input array. The callback returns a new value and `map()` returns a new array of all the new values.

---

test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>find contents test case</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="OCalaisBox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="OCalaisHeadRow">
        <td colspan="4" class="OCalaisTitleBar">Topics in this article</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="OCalaisList indexNormalText" valign=top width="25%" >
          <div class="OCalaisHeader">Country</div>
          <ul >
            <li><a href="/category/country/nigeria">Nigeria</a></li>
            <li><a href="/category/country/bosnia-and-herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

  <script>
    array = ( [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.OCalaisList>ul>li>a'), function(item) { return item.textContent; }));
    console.log(array);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ^_^. So I tried this out (the oneliner), and it gives me an empty list; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the complete code you are using. I've added the complete test case that works in my Firefox.

Comment: You could try the less restrictive selector `'.OCalaisList li a'`.

Comment: I've just altered `.innerHTML` to `.textContent`. So you will get "Bosnia and Herzegowina" when the content is: "<b>Bosnia</b> and <b>Herzegovina</b>" which is more appropriate to this case. You want unformatted content, not HTML. This way you can also select the hole <li> tags and get their contents, no matter there is some hyperlink and formatting code or not.

Comment: Your code is roughly correct but not robust. It will misfire. It looks like the OP is on Al Jazeera pages and lots of things use that structure -- on pages that use it. Not all of them do.

Comment: @Brock Adams The environment of the code hasn't been specified. Another approach to retrieve nodes with more capabilities would be an XPath expression, especially in GM, but this would be much harder to understand to a newbie. Btw.: What does "OP" mean in this community - I've often read. I only know it as "Operator" in other contexts.

Comment: "OP" means original poster -- the question asker.  Yes, the environment hasn't been specified, but it's still clear that the given structure is generic, so your selector will yield a bunch of false positives.  The thing to do is to key off the `<div class="OCalaisHeader">Country</div>` or something else specific to country.